# Generation of combination of matrix rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, combinations, python-itertools

For example I am having matrix with 64 rows. I want to get all the combinations looks like we can take 1 element from rows 0 to 3, 1 element from 4 to 7 etc.
So I need 16 rows from matrix.
My idea is making 16 matrix with 4 rows and try to choose one from each. But my code doesn't work. Task is getting all the combinations of rows where we take one from all groups of 4 rows.
My code:

```
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 1, (64,64))  # random 64X64 matrix with zeros and ones
matrix1 = [matrix[4*k:4*k+4:1] for k in range(16)]  # getting 16 matrix like 0..3,4...7 etc
for checker in itertools.combinations(itertools.chain([[matrix1[i] for i in range(16)]])):
    print(str(checker))  # do smth
```

Comment: I would try it the other way round. First create all combination of row numbers using itertools.

Comment: its the first idea I got,but its only example and my task is too big to convert sets of int to matrix rows

Comment: I am sorry, but your description is very confusing as to what are you trying to do. Could you, please, reformulate?

Comment: To understand what I meant execute the following code `for x in itertools.product(*[range(i, i+4) for i in range(0,64,4)]): print(x)`

Comment: thank you,gonna try this

Answer (score 0):

For something as large as what you have, its very difficult to print the results, so i will give you a working example for something smaller-

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations
matrix = np.random.randint(0, 5, (4,2))
print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[4 3]
 [3 0]
 [1 3]
 [3 3]]
```

Getting the permutations:

```
k = permutations(matrix, 2)
for sub_matrix in k:
    print(sub_matrix)
```

Output:

```
(array([4, 3]), array([3, 0]))
(array([4, 3]), array([1, 3]))
(array([4, 3]), array([3, 3]))
(array([3, 0]), array([4, 3]))
(array([3, 0]), array([1, 3]))
(array([3, 0]), array([3, 3]))
(array([1, 3]), array([4, 3]))
(array([1, 3]), array([3, 0]))
(array([1, 3]), array([3, 3]))
(array([3, 3]), array([4, 3]))
(array([3, 3]), array([3, 0]))
(array([3, 3]), array([1, 3]))
```

So in your example you'd pass 4 as the second argument to `permutations`.
**I must warn you though, you will get a whooping 15,249,024 permutations.**
EDIT:
To get the combinations and NOT the permutations, you'd replace `permutations` with `combinations`. Even in this case you'd get 635,376 results. Watch out before printing!

Comment: its a full combitations solution. But I need something another. For example
all combitations of element from first two rows and element from 3'th and 4'th rows.
It gonna be like 
43 13
43 33
30 13
30 33